# Email cannot be get pickupdirectoryiis

Tags: email, smtp

We are implementing email code.

```
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.pickupdirectoryiis;
```

But unable the error cannot be get pickupdirectory.....
please tell me what is the error

Comment: @user582977: in what language are your working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the **PickupDirectoryLocation** property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.deliverymethod.aspx